# How to create anonymous application page with out master page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have an html page.I want to make a new application page in SharePoint with the contents of my html page.I don't need master page because i don't want the look and feel of SharePoint.My page is anonymous page.How can i create an application page without master page in SharePoint?

Comment: use SharePoint Designer to create a new aspx page. By default it will be without a masterpage.

Comment: @Mike I am using VS

Comment: how to create application pages in designer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a custom application page, your page must inherit from the LayoutsPageBase base class and must use one of the dynamic tokens listed below.
Dynamic tokens:

~masterurl/default.master – The application page references the master page file that is stored in the MasterUrl property.

~masterurl/custom.master – The application page references the master page file that is stored in the CustomMasterUrl property.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537530(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537530%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question or requirements, but:

1. Deploy your HTML file to _layouts folder
2. Deploy your file to any document library

no?

Or your page is not a simple HTMl markup and needs to inherit from ApplicationPage?

Comment: I want to add my html contents to my custom aspx page in layouts.I want to know whether master page is mandatory for application pages?